# Use table of number as filter in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, numbers

I want to use a Table of Number as a filter in a select statement.

This is the Table of Numbers:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE AUTOCONTROLE2.ListNumbers AS TABLE OF NUMBER(10)
```

This is a little test sql:

```
declare
testvar number;
ActiviteitSAC autocontrole2.ListNumbers := autocontrole2.ListNumbers(189449, 189456, 189473);
begin
    select  count(O.pap_id) into testvar
    from    pap_operator O
    where   O.PAP_OPERATOR_ID in (ActiviteitSAC(1), ActiviteitSAC(2), ActiviteitSAC(3));
end;
```

I want to replace the ActiviteitSAC(1), ActiviteitSAC(2), ActiviteitSAC(3) by something like
"select * from ActiviteitSAC".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT count( o.pap_id) 
  INTO testvar
  FROM pap_operator o
 WHERE o.pap_operator_id IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(ActiveiteitSAC) );
```

should do it.